# C/C++ alternative for matlab reshape and permute functions

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I need to port a piece of code from matlab into C or C++. Matlab implementation of the code extensively use reshape and permute functions to manipulate the layout of multidimensional arrays. Is there any library in c or c++ to get effect of these two matlab routines. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried first?

Comment: right now i have no implementation of any of these two routines, if this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`OpenCV`**](http://opencv.org/) library, which contains similar [**`Mat::reshape()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) routines to do transforms and permutations.

Comment: is there way in openCV to get around the permute routine because that is the complicated part i guess.

Comment: @user42948 Isn't it what you supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "permute"? You mean "permutation" in the mathematical sense? If so, check out C++ STL next_permutation(). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: @scai by permute i mean rearranging the order of indices in multidimensional arrays.
assume x: 4x5x3x2 array
then permute(x,[4 3 1 2]) returns a 2x3x4x5 array

Answer (score 0):

If someone has found the answer for the Matlab permute function I am interrested.

I think the reshape can be done with `boost::multi_array::reshape`.